# Azure bot Nodejs Function calls

Tags: node.js, azure, bots, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I am trying to call a dialog in the bot which has to go to specific function, Here is the scenario...
 I have a dialog bot as shown below

```
bot.dialog('/Welcome', [
function(session){
builder.Prompts.text(session, "Welcome to the Bot");
},
function (session, args) {
// Has some code 
},
function (session, args){
//has some code
}......
```

When ever i do replace dialog ie.

```
bot.replaceDialog('/Welcome')
```

it should not go to the first function ie. **Welcome to the Bot** It should skip this and go to next function.

Is there any way to accomplish this in azure bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple if you look at their article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-replace

Their example is like below

```
// This dialog prompts the user for a phone number. 
// It will re-prompt the user if the input does not match a pattern for phone number.
bot.dialog('phonePrompt', [
    function (session, args) {
        if (args && args.reprompt) {
            builder.Prompts.text(session, "Enter the number using a format of either: '(555) 123-4567' or '555-123-4567' or '5551234567'")
        } else {
            builder.Prompts.text(session, "What's your phone number?");
        }
    },
    function (session, results) {
        var matched = results.response.match(/\d+/g);
        var number = matched ? matched.join('') : '';
        if (number.length == 10 || number.length == 11) {
            session.userData.phoneNumber = number; // Save the number.
            session.endDialogWithResult({ response: number });
        } else {
            // Repeat the dialog
            session.replaceDialog('phonePrompt', { reprompt: true });
        }
    }
]);
```

So yours would be something like below

```
bot.dialog('/Welcome', [
function(session, args, next){
if (!args || args.prompt)
    builder.Prompts.text(session, "Welcome to the Bot");
else
    next();
},
function (session, args) {
// Has some code 
},
function (session, args){
//has some code
}......
```

and you will call it like below

```
bot.replaceDialog('/Welcome', {prompt: false}))
```

Comment: Hi Tarun, Thanks for the update, But your solution doesn't work as per my requirements. If i parse replaceDialog('/Welcome', {prompt: false})).. It will however not go to *if* condition however it will be in the same function ie. it doesn't go to the next function automatically

Comment: @VinayJayaram, thanks for the feedback. I assume it is the `function (session, args) {
// Has some code 
},` you had? I will take a look why

Comment: It is not going to function (session, args) { // Has some code }, . It is sitting idle in function(session, args){
if (!args || args.prompt)
    builder.Prompts.text(session, "Welcome to the Bot");
}